# In knockoutjs how can I bind to a property and have the view updated when the property changes?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Possibly a misconception in my learning here.

I'm setting my viewmodel binding is set to "observe" a property of a javascript object. I created a interval timer to toggle the property of the object but my UI is not reflecting the change. How can I notify the framework that the property of the object has changed and update it accordingly?

Live Example:http://liveweave.com/Xfrcrv

```
<p>Section 1 <span data-bind="visible : hasErrors">***</span></p>

<script>
var myObj = {sectionhasErrors : true}
var vm = {
  hasErrors : ko.observable(myObj.sectionhasErrors)
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
var iTimer = setInterval(function () {
  myObj.sectionhasErrors = !myObj.sectionhasErrors
  console.log('toggled!');
},5000);  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout cannot "observe" individual properties of an object. You would have to put the entire object inside an observable.

```
<p>Section 1 <span data-bind="visible : myObj().hasErrors">***</span></p>
```

---

```
var myObj = {
  hasErrors: true
}

var vm = {
    myObj: ko.observable(myObj)
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

var iTimer = setInterval(function () {
  var myObj = vm.myObj();
  myObj.hasErrors = false;
  vm.myObj(myObj);
  console.log('toggled!');
},5000);
```

It does seem to me that you haven't grasped some basic Knockout concepts. I would recommend that you work through the [tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) on their website.